# Dependent or Independent...a little intuition

Tags: time-series, probability, independence, intuition

I have a time series that describe the power consumption of a building. For every hour of the day I have a measurement (e.g Hour 0 = 2.3 kWh, Hour 1 = 4.2 kWh etc).
Do you believe that the measurements for different hours are dependent or independent variables?

Comment: In a time series, autocorrelation function is more important than what you are asking. Your measurements are likely to show a diurnal pattern, and measurements will be highly correlated with neighboring measurements and less correlated with (temporally) distant measurements.

Comment: kWh are units of energy, not power. Completely irrelevant to the question, but important for your reputation with clients? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilowatt_hour

Comment: @Nick, yes, good point, but if 2.3 kWh were spent in 1 h, then certainly the average power during this hour was 2.3 kW. The exact wording used by the OP actually looks fine to me.

Comment: You are clearly correct that you can convert one unit to another, but I don't see that undermining my small point. I'll stick to my comment, because you don't consume power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see "dependent or independent variables", I do not think of "statistically independent", but rather experimentation and modeling, where there are dependent and independent variables. [Edited per amoeba's comment.]

So if you are doing a regression to predict electricity usage, electricity usage would be your dependent (target) value. Other measurements (temperature, etc) and lagged values for these measurements (temperature two hours ago, or temperature same time yesterday) and of the electricity usage itself (usage two hours ago, usage same time yesterday) would be your independent variables.

If you are asking if each hour's electricity usage is independent of other values, Dilip Sarwate's comment is correct: time series like this have autocorrelation and an hour is not independent of the previous hour.

Comment: It seems that the OP referred to the concept of *statistical independence*. How is this non-standard? Still, good point about the ambiguity of the term "(in)dependent".

Comment: +1 after the edit. "Statistically dependent" with [40k hits on google](https://www.google.com/search?q="statistically+dependent") is definitely a well-accepted term, even though "statistically independent" does yield an order of magnitude more hits.

Comment: @amoeba ; If $E$ is electricity usage and $T$ is temperature then $E$ is the dependent variable, but it is also statistically dependent on $T$ because the regression models $\mathbb{E}(E|_T)$ I think ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation by contradiction.  If it was independent, that would mean time of day doesn't impact the power consumption at all. Do you think the power consumption of a building is the same during the daylight when all the lights are on as it as at night when everyone is sleeping? Obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, knowledge of previous power consumptions improves the prediction for power consumption of the next hour, even after taking into account the periodicity.

Comment: ... meaning that they are dependent or independent? Somehow this answer looks unfinished.

Comment: As much as this question makes sense, for each hour, a power consumtion for this hour is an independent variable, and a power consumptions for previous hour are dependent variables.